# MooTools: How to addEvents to non-child elements with .each?

Tags: class, loops, mootools, each

what i'm trying to accomplish is to make each header of a certain class to invoke the 'slide' method on it's sibling of another class (in this case 'accordion_header' and 'accordion_content' respectively).  i'm targeting classes, because, well, it makes sense, right?

here's the code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    console.log('trying to set click-on-header to open sib div\n');
    $$('.accordion_header').each.addEvent('click', function(e) {
        $('.accordion_content').slide('toggle');
    }); 
});
```

here's the HTML.  the content is irrelevant, but the structure is the same for all such 'accordions':

```
<div id="itemOne">
    <div class="accoridon_header header_highlight">
        <h2 class="stripeToRight gradient">#</h2>
    </div>  <!-- end of accoridon_header -->    

    <div class="accordion_content">
        #
    </div>  <!-- end of accordion_content -->
</div>  <!-- end of itemOne -->
```

needless to say, but likely should, the code isn't functioning as i expected. what did i miss?

WR!

PS: i'd like to add/remove an additional class to the header to indicate state...is there a quick method for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let's make some things clear:

`elements.each.addEvent` is not correct, you can use `addEvent` directly on a collection like `elements.addEvent`.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    console.log('trying to set click-on-header to open sib div\n');

    $$('.accordion_header').addEvent('click', function(e) { 

          this.getParent().getElement('.accordion_content').slide('toggle'); //get accordion content

    });


});
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ykDY/)

if you want to add/remove class inside the click callback you can use [`this.addClass('class')`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aaddClass) with [`this.removeClass('class')`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aremoveClass), or - better in this case - [`this.toggleClass('class')`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3atoggleClass)

p.s. on your html you have accoridon instead of accordion ;)

Comment: sweet!  you made things VERY clear.  :)  thank you.  i'm sure @MattiSG's answer would work, but it's not as accessible to me as this.  it solves the question!  :D  and with bonus content!  :D  also, caught the typo.  thx yet again...  :)

Comment: can i set the initial state in this fashion as well: $$('.accordion_content').slide('slideOut');?

Comment: Yep, you can .. but in that way you make the animation at the page loading, so it's better to use `$$('.accordion_content').slide('hide');`. See http://jsfiddle.net/3ykDY/1/

Comment: fab-tastic!  perfect answer: clear and to the point.  :)  thank you.  MooTools FTW.

Comment: @WhiteRau Remember to accept this answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it solved your problem and was what you chose  :)  If my own answer looks like a good one but not as good as this one (which is true), you can still upvote it to show approval  ;)

Comment: @WhiteRau you're welcome. MattiSG thanks :) ..and I agree, if WhiteRau finds your answer helpful and/or good (I find it too) the upvote is 'needed' ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $$('.accordion_header').each.addEvent(…
```

This call (or rather, lack of) is your problem. Read the [documentation of `each`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array%3aArray-each) and actually *call* the `each` method rather than trying to *access* the `addEvent` property of the `each` property, which of course does not exist.

That will lead you to a call that should look like this:

```
 Array.each($$('.accordion_header'), function(currentHeader) {
      currentHeader.addEvent(…
```

Comment: This is not at all correct! This will return an array (collection) not an object. {...}.each(func) is deprecated however not relevant to this post. [...].each(func) is not deprecated and is in fact native in many browser mootools simply provides support to non compliant browsers. alternatively you can all Array.each([...], func) much like with objects.

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com Oops, right, I had used `Object` instead of `Array`. It doesn't invalidate the answer beyond the namespacing, but one can indeed use the shorter `[…].each` syntax.

Comment: Disagree. "This call (or rather, lack of) is your problem." is correct. Even though this has been updated with the correct namespace and the fact that you remove reference to the deprecation of array.each Really really really dislike this line: "That will lead you to a call that should look like this:" You can loop through an array like that if you would like, but your code is bloated. The beautiful thing about mooTools is the markup! Clean and maintainable.

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com The _“markup”_? Could you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: arr.each(func); is much cleaner neater shorter that your alleged comment of ... will lead you to a call that "should" look like this: Array.(arr,func); Anywho, have a great night! Happy coding!